# Highlight new data being copied over

Tags: excel, vba, with-statement

I have the below coding that if there isn't a match, it copies over the "new" information (columns 1 to 9). Can someone please suggest code to add to highlight each new row of data that is added so I can easily discern between the existing data and new rows? Thanks!

```
Sub CompareSheets()

Dim laws As Worksheet
Set laws = Sheets("LookAhead")
Dim galreqws As Worksheet
Set galreqws = Sheets("galreq")

Dim RowsMaster As Integer, Rows2 As Integer
RowsMaster = laws.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Rows2 = galreqws.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Get the number of used rows for each sheet


With Worksheets("galreq")
    For i = 2 To Rows2
    ' Loop through Sheet 2
        For j = 2 To RowsMaster
        ' Loop through the Master sheet
            If .Cells(i, 4) = laws.Cells(j, 4) And .Cells(i, 6) = laws.Cells(j, 6) And .Cells(i, 8) = laws.Cells(j, 8) Then
            ' If a match is found:
                laws.Cells(j, 5) = .Cells(i, 5)
                ' Copy in contact info
                Exit For
                ' No point in continuing the search for that company
            ElseIf j = RowsMaster Then
            ' If we got to the end of the Master sheet
            ' and haven't found a company match
                RowsMaster = RowsMaster + 1
                ' Increment the number of rows
                For k = 1 To 9 ' Change 3 to however many fields Sheet2 has
                    laws.Cells(RowsMaster, k) = .Cells(i, k)
                    ' Copy the data from Sheet2 in on the bottom row of Master
                Next
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the background of a cell using the `Range.Interior.Color` property.  It's a little tricky to figure out what number to put in there to get the right color.  I will usually find the color I want first, then determine the corresponding number, by selecting it and typing `?Selection.Interior.Color` into the immediate window, which will print the number immediately below.

Try `laws.Cells(j, 5).Interior.Color = 8210719` on for size.

Comment: Great solution! I was able to add it right below my code line that is copying the data over. The only issue, it did color one line of my existing data in blue and didn't color the last line of my new data. Any idea how to get the highlighting to shift down by 1 line?

Comment: VBA will only do what you tell it to do.  I didn't spend much time with your code to figure out exactly where to color.  `Cells(j, 5) ` is just a reference to the "j"th row and 5th column.  You can put any expression that evaluates to an integer there (like `Cells(j + 1, 5)`).  Looks like you also are printing something on `laws.Cells(RowMaster, k) = .Cells(i,k)` so that might be appropriate too.

Comment: Awesome, I was able to add the +1 in the existing code and it worked perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: How would I color the entire row of new data if I wanted to? Assume there are 5 columns? As you know, it currently is just highlighting the cell in the 5th column of each row.

Comment: Lucky for you, the Range object has a `Range.EntireRow` property, which, predictably, refers to the entire row contained by the range.  `Cells(i,j)` is a Range object.  So you can use `Cells(i,j).EntireRow.Interior.Color`  For a reference guide to the Range object, see the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn301006.aspx

Comment: The only issue with doing that (which seems to be the same result as laws.Rows(j)..Interior.Color = 8210719) is it highlights the ENTIRE row well beyond where my data ends column wise. Is there a way to limit it to only 5 columns width?

Comment: To combine multiple cells into a range, you can use the `Range` function, and pass the start and end cell. `Range(laws.Cells(i,1), laws.Cells(i,5)).Interior.Color`

Comment: `Cells(i, j).Resize(1, 5).Interior.Color = ...`